# Rails fields_for, optional fields and validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, fields-for

I have an Event model that `has many :bands, through: :event_bands`. The `band` model `validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true`.

On Event creation, the user selects the bands from a multi-select like this:

```
<p>
    <%= f.label t(:band_playing) %>
    <%= f.collection_select :band_ids, Band.order(:name), :id, :name, {}, {multiple: true} %>
</p>
```

However, if the user doesn't find the appropriate band, I would like them to be able to create the Band on that same form with the association using `accepts_nested_attributes_for :bands` in my Event model.

So, I added this to my form, which I hide/show with some jQuery:

```
    <div id="new_bands">
        <p>
            <%= f.fields_for :bands do |ff| %>
                <%= ff.label "New Band Name" %>
              <%= ff.text_field :name, class: "form-control half" %>
            <% end %>
      </p>
    </div>
```

However, for `fields_for` to work correctly, I need to build the association my Events controller like this:

```
def new
  @event = current_user.events.build
  1.times {@event.bands.build}
end
```

This is working great if the user needs to add a new band to the form, however, it's breaking form submission if the user isn't adding a new band. It breaks because the line in the controller `1.times {@event.bands.build}` builds a new Band, but the form is submitted without a name to pass Band validations.

It seems like for this to work, I need a way to call `1.times {@event.bands.build}` when the `fields_for` part of my form is toggled, but I don't think that's even possible.

I tried using `reject_if` in the Event model: `accepts_nested_attributes_for :bands, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['name'].blank? }`, but it doesn't work. My searching make me think this is failing because `reject_if` isn't run until after the model is saved, but validations on Band.name are run before it is saved?

Right now, I have all my tests passing by putting this in my controller:

```
def create
    @event = current_user.events.build(event_params)
    @event.bands.each do |band|
        if band.name.blank?
            band.destroy
        end
    end
    if @event.save
    blablabla
```

But that seems like it goes against the whole skinny controller, fat model approach.

Answer (score 2):

One easy workaround:

Use two different definitions for your strong params. One including and one excluding the params for band.

```
def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:name, :field1, ..., :fieldn)
end

def event_params_with_band
    params.require(:event).permit(:name, :field1, ..., :fieldn, band_attributes: [:name, ..])
end
```

Apply some logic before `@event = current_user.events.build(event_params)` to merge or not the band parameters. For instance:

```
def create
    if params[:event][:new_band]=="true" # let's assume this comes from a 'tick' in your form
        myparams=event_params_with_band
    else
        myparams=event_params
    end
    @event = current_user.events.build(myparams)
    if @event.save
        # your responses etc
    end
end
```

I suppose you still have to build the relation for event_bands, but I figure you know how to do this.

Comment: Cool suggestion, I played around with this and it worked quite well. I ended up following the token approach covered here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields-revised to clean things up a bit more.